# How to make this data control reusable for different content and data?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, webforms, repeater

I'm using ASP.NET Web Forms, and I've got a `Repeater` control to display some data. Currently it looks like this:

```html
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="blah" OnItemDataBound="blah" OnItemCommand="blah">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="itemList">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li runat="server" id="listItem" class="itemNormal" onmouseover="this.className = 'itemHover';" onmouseout="this.className = 'itemNormal';">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_select" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" style="display: none;"></asp:LinkButton>
            <strong>Date/Time:</strong> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "date") %><br />
            <strong>Details:</strong> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "details") %><br />
            <strong>Status:</strong> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status") %><br />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

This list has hover behaviour, etc. and I'd like to reuse the same style of list across my project, just with different data (really just replacing the three lines with `<strong>` tags in). However, I obviously don't want to copypaste and change it every time it's used, so I thought I'd try and make it into a User Control:

```html
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="blah" OnItemDataBound="blah" OnItemCommand="blah">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="itemList">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li runat="server" id="listItem" class="itemNormal" onmouseover="this.className = 'itemHover';" onmouseout="this.className = 'itemNormal';">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_select" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" style="display: none;"></asp:LinkButton>
            <%= DataString %>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And in my corresponding class in CodeBehind:

```cs
public string DataString { get; set; }
```

So my main aim was to do this:

```html
<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="blah" DataString="<strong>Date/Time:</strong><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "date") %> ETC..." />
```

But it seemed that ASP.NET wanted to evaluate the `<% %>` in the string there and then, and I tried different ways to get around it such as this:

```html
<% string theDataString = "<strong>Date/Time:</strong> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "date") %>"; %>
<uc:MyUserControl runat="server" ID="blah" DataString='<%= theDataString %>' />
```

But I ran into trouble again with the closing `%>` in `theDataString`, and even after replacing it with something like `{0: %}` (to escape the % sign: can't remember the exact syntax), which did escape it correctly, I discovered that you can't actually use the `<%= %>` inside an attribute, which was annoying.

My last-ditch attempt was to set `DataString` in my page's CodeBehind, and the HTML `<strong>` rendered correctly, but ASP.NET didn't evaluate the `<%# %>` and just spat it out literally. So I'm kind of stuck as I can't think of anything else... (by the way I'm still relatively new to ASP.NET)

I'm not even sure this is a good way to go about it - previously I thought about making it into a templated user control but this method seemed simpler and it was something I already knew how to do, or so I thought. So any help with this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Just to be clear, my emphasis here is on the *re-usability* of this particular control - so I will be able to display different types of data records in this style of list (clickable, highlight behaviour etc).

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have three lines appear as **bold** instead of normal text, then your best bet is to use something more geared towards website-display than something programmatic and heavy-handed like a dynamic server-side user control. For example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="blah" OnItemDataBound="blah" OnItemCommand="blah">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul class="itemList">
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li runat="server" id="listItem" class="itemNormal" onmouseover="this.className = 'itemHover';" onmouseout="this.className = 'itemNormal';">
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btn_select" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" style="display: none;"></asp:LinkButton>
            <span class="displayMode">Date/Time:</span> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "date") %><br />
            <span class="displayMode">Details:</span> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "details") %><br />
            <span class="displayMode">Status:</span> <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "status") %><br />
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And then, programmtically show:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .displayMode { font-weight: bold; }
    /* and/or */
    .displayMode { text-decoration: underline; }
</style>
```

Use the right tool for the job, in this case, I don't feel as though server-side code is the right way to accomplish this task. If, on the other hand, you need to change the content of the insides of your `<li>` tags, then yes you would have to do it in C#. However, if that were the case you could easily bind it to a different object or use a different control or inherit the control or any number of other methods. For your specific case, just use standard HTML manipulation techniques.

Comment: Ok thanks, but could you clarify that last paragraph - I do want to change the content in the `<li>` but it's always going to have data binding syntax in. Eg instead I might have `Customer Name: <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "name") %>` and some other, **different** fields. But the `Repeater`, `li` and templates, styles etc. would all be the same, so is there a way to do all this without just copypasting it all and altering the `li` content manually? That's my emphasis - the reusability. And I'm using the server side control because the list's contents comes from a data source.

Comment: If that's the case, I'd use an intermediary instead of directly data-binding. Pass in a model class to the usercontrol with fields for `CustomerName`, `Date/Time` etc. and then in the page, create instances of this model class and populate its properties with the appropriate values from your data.

Comment: OK. How would you get it to co-operate with the Repeater? Do you mean, say, modify its `ItemTemplate` in code using the model? And I suppose all of this will have to be done in CodeBehind, save for specifying the class name to use, eg `<uc:MyUserControl ... DataModelClass="CustomerDataModel" />`, and use reflection to instantiate the class? Is that what you mean?